# Get possible combinations (of size N) that match specific range criteria

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, range, combinations

```
// Input array
$arr = [
    'A' => '9-11',
    'B' => '9-12',
    'C' => '12-14',
    'D' => '13-14',
    'E' => '15-16',
    'F' => '15-16',
    'G' => '13-14',
    'H' => '14-16'
];

// ranges
$start = 9;
$end = 16;

// Desired outputs:
A + C + E (9-11, 12-14, 15-16)
A + C + F (9-11, 12-14, 15-16)
A + C + H (9-11, 12-14, 14-16)

B + D + E (9-12, 13-14, 15-16)
B + G + F (9-12, 13-14, 15-16)
B + G + H (9-12, 13-14, 14-16)
```

So it means, every combination MUST start with 9 ( as we `$start = 9` ) and try to get up to 16 ( ie. the `$end = 16` IF AVAILABLE ) with `n` elements in each combination( here, `n = 3`).

I searched the web for many problems and tried something of myself. But unfortunately, they didn't even get a title bit closer of the solution. The problem I'm working is different from above example and complex.

Comment: _and tried something of myself_ - Show us.

Comment: @Leggendario I tired some of StackOverflow solutions. eg. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19067556/php-algorithm-to-generate-all-combinations-of-a-specific-size-from-a-single-set but I didn't setup my condition to get the result what I want. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this in multiple iterations:

1. Create a recursive function that simply builds combinations of size `n` out of given array.
   (as pre-processing step you want to change `9-11` into `[9,11]` so that you can easily check range later, e.g. `>= $range[0]` for min ... `<= $range[1]` for max)

   - [PHP algorithm to generate all combinations of a specific size from a single set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19067556/php-algorithm-to-generate-all-combinations-of-a-specific-size-from-a-single-set) will help with this step
2. Just then add condition to filter out combinations that don't start with `$start`.
3. Then add condition to filter out those that don't end with `$end`

---

**EDIT:** A good start could be:

```
function appendElements($elements, & $dst) {
    foreach ($elements as $ele) $dst[] = $ele;
}

function buildTouples($map, $start, $end, $size, $currentSize, $touplesToExtend) {
    if ($currentSize == $size) return $touplesToExtend;
    if ($map === []) return [];

    $allTouples = [];
    foreach ($map as $key => $range) {
        unset($map[$key]);
        foreach ($touplesToExtend as $toupleToExtend) {
            $toupleToExtend[] = $key;
            $newTouples = 
               buildTouples($map, $start, $end, $size, $currentSize+1, [$toupleToExtend]);
            appendElements($newTouples, $allTouples);
        }
    }
    return $allTouples;
}
```

used as:

```
$map = [
    'A' => [9,11],
    'B' => [9,12],
    'C' => [12,14],
    'D' => [13,14],
    'E' => [15,16],
    'F' => [15,16],
    'G' => [13,14],
    'H' => [14,16]
];
$start = 9;
$end = 16;
$size = 3;
$touples = buildTouples($map, $start, $end, $size, 0, [[]]);

foreach ($touples as $touple) {
    foreach ($touple as $val) echo $val;
    echo ', ';
}
```

outputs:

> ABC, ABD, ABE, ABF, ABG, ABH, ACD, ACE, ACF, ACG, ACH, ADE, ADF, ADG, ADH, AEF, AEG, AEH, AFG, AFH, AGH, BCD, BCE, BCF, BCG, BCH, BDE, BDF, BDG, BDH, BEF, BEG, BEH, BFG, BFH, BGH, CDE, CDF, CDG, CDH, CEF, CEG, CEH, CFG, CFH, CGH, DEF, DEG, DEH, DFG, DFH, DGH, EFG, EFH, EGH, FGH,

Comment: @All inputs will be in range and its sure and step 2 (of above link) includes combination with `b/c` as start, but for me, all combinations need to be start of 9( the start range) but might now always end with 16(end range and its OK). what should I do for that case? That is the solution I'm seeking for.

Comment: @TheSystemRestart: Check now :) Now you just need to tweak it to avoid building touples that start or end with something out of specified `$start` / `$end`.