# Get all ordered, contiguous combinations of an array's elements

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm

I want to get all possible phrases (which actually exist) in a sentence as

```
$str = 'word1 word2 word3 word4';

$output = array ('word1 word2 word3', 'word1 word2', 
                 'word2 word3 word4', 'word3 word4', 'word2 word3');
```

To do so, I create an array of words as,

```
$words = explode(' ', $str);
```

There are several questions here explaining how to build all combinations of the elements of an array, but how can I make all the combinations while preserving the original order?

How can I make the array of `$output` out of `$words`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19067556/php-algorithm-to-generate-all-combinations-of-a-specific-size-from-a-single-set#

Comment: @mayursaptal that's the opposite of what I want by disregarding the order for a specific size. I want different sizes of the same order.

Comment: Why isn't `word1 word3` a possible combination in expected output ?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Because it is not in the sequential order. I want to get all phrases (substrings) in the sentence (string).

Comment: Why isn't `word1 word2 word3 word4` also one of the expected output ?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya yes it can be, a string is a substring of itself too.

Comment: @Googlebot Hint: two nested loops; one running from start to end; another end to start; also use `array_slice()`.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya I thought about that but then cannot get the middle substrings like `word2 word3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- We can use [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) function to take a chunk out of the input array. It will also ensure that the order is maintained, as well as the combinations are of the successive values (as per the original array).
- Now, we need to use two nested loops, to determine `$offset`, and `$length` for the chunk.
- `$offset` value will basically loop from the beginning to end; `$length` will initially be count of remaining values from the offset, and it will be decrementing upto 2 (we don't want single values as combinations).

Try the following (**[Rextester DEMO](https://rextester.com/PTE85172)**):

```
$str = 'word1 word2 word3 word4';
$words = explode(' ', $str);

$combinations = array();

// offset from start to end of the words
for($offset = 0; $offset < count($words); $offset++) {

    // length from available remaining words to 2
    for ($length = count($words) - $offset; $length > 1; $length--) {

        // get the array chunk
        $combinations[] = array_slice($words, $offset, $length);
    }
}

// test output
print_r($combinations);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => word1
            [1] => word2
            [2] => word3
            [3] => word4
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => word1
            [1] => word2
            [2] => word3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => word1
            [1] => word2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => word2
            [1] => word3
            [2] => word4
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => word2
            [1] => word3
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => word3
            [1] => word4
        )

)
```