# How do you generate a list of all possible strings given a generator of characters and a length?

Tags: php, recursion, generator

For example given `['a', 'b']` (as a generator) and 2 as a length

the function would output a generator that would yield:

```
'',
'a',
'b',
'ab'
'ba'
'aa'
'bb'
```

or given `['a']` and a length of 3:

```
'',
'a',
'aa',
'aaa',
```

As you could imagine this set would get a lot larger if more letters were added or length was increased, it should list all permutations of the given characters up until the length

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10223120/5897602) could help with the permutations, then its just dealing with the length. Have you tried anything yet we could see? This is an interesting problem.

Comment: You could start with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19067556/php-algorithm-to-generate-all-combinations-of-a-specific-size-from-a-single-set) and change the `sampling` function to fit your need or use it in another loop for the different length

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a fairly self-explanatory solution.

```
//Returns all permuations of a certain length.
function perm($ls, $len) {
    if($len <= 0) {
        yield '';
    }
    else {
        foreach ($ls as $x) {
            foreach(perm($ls, $len-1) as $i) {
               yield $x.$i;
            }
        }
    }
}

//Returns all permuations of all lengths less or equal to the given integer.
function all_perm($ls, $len) {
    //$ls = iterator_to_array($ls);
    for($x=$len; $x>=0; $x--) {
        foreach(perm($ls, $len-$x) as $string) {
            yield $string;
        }
    }
}
```

Simply call *all_perm* with your array and maximum length. If the argument absolutely have to be a generator, uncomment *$ls = iterator_to_array($ls);*.

Comment: Can you reference where you have this from?

Comment: @Blackbam I wrote it just now.

Comment: Nice. Short and effective.

Comment: Thank you, my attempts at this were nowhere near as elegant, or functional

Comment: Its a great idea to use generators and the yield keyword.