# Generate all combination from two arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have two array like these:

```
$a = array("abc","defs","ghi");
$b = array("abcs","def","ghis");
```

I want all the combination of strings like these:

```
abc defs ghi
abc def ghi
abc def ghis
abc defs ghis
abcs defs ghi
abcs def ghi
abcs def ghis
abcs defs ghis
```

How to do this in php?

PS - array can be of any length but both arrays size are always same.

PPS - The accepted answer given in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567082/how-to-generate-in-php-all-combinations-of-items-in-multiple-arrays) is not giving me the correct result. It is giving the following result:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => abc [1] => abcs ) [1] => Array ( [0] => abc [1] => def ) [2] => Array ( [0] => abc [1] => ghi ) [3] => Array ( [0] => defs [1] => abcs ) [4] => Array ( [0] => defs [1] => def ) [5] => Array ( [0] => defs [1] => ghi ) [6] => Array ( [0] => ghi [1] => abcs ) [7] => Array ( [0] => ghi [1] => def ) [8] => Array ( [0] => ghi [1] => ghi ) )
```

Comment: Do you mean like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567082/how-to-generate-in-php-all-combinations-of-items-in-multiple-arrays

Comment: Step 1 merge both arrays since your logic needs all of them anyway. Step 2 run a recursive function to generate combinations. Look in to this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19067556/php-algorithm-to-generate-all-combinations-of-a-specific-size-from-a-single-set

Comment: @Auris The order is important for me. So, I can't merge the array.

Comment: In that case look in to the answer linked by The fourth bird. It will get you started.

Comment: @Auris Please see the updated question.

Comment: @Thefourthbird It is not working for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert your array to this,

```
$a    = ["abc", "defs", "ghi"];
$b    = ["abcs", "def", "ghis"];
$temp = array_map(null, $a, $b); // this conversion we call it transposing of array
function combinations($arrays)
{
    $result = [];
    $arrays = array_values($arrays);
    $sizeIn = sizeof($arrays);
    $size   = $sizeIn > 0 ? 1 : 0;
    foreach ($arrays as $array) {
        $size = $size * sizeof($array);
    }
    for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++) {
        $result[$i] = [];
        for ($j = 0; $j < $sizeIn; $j++) {
            array_push($result[$i], current($arrays[$j]));
        }
        for ($j = ($sizeIn - 1); $j >= 0; $j--) {
            if (next($arrays[$j])) {
                break;
            } elseif (isset($arrays[$j])) {
                reset($arrays[$j]);
            }
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
$res = combinations($temp);
// imploding all the values internally with space
$temp = array_map(function($item){
    return implode(" ", $item);
},$res);
// looping to show the data
foreach($temp as $val){
    echo $val."\n";
}
```

Once you convert your array using array_map, then I used help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8567479/11608095).

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/EoXmD).

**Output**

```
abc defs ghi
abc defs ghis
abc def ghi
abc def ghis
abcs defs ghi
abcs defs ghis
abcs def ghi
abcs def ghis
```